# How to make each created buttons for detail to be refered to each data

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm using firebase to retrieve data onto html page, and I want it so that the name are printed out on the html as a list, and append the button next to the each name from firebase, and each button, when clicked, shows address and email associated with that name.

so far, I have gotten it to work, except that the appended buttons all give alert to the same last data input. How do I make it so that it becomes associated with its right name?

Here's my data on firebase:
addressbook-6d9e9
information
-MCqyNHtvbuQxlYrp6Qz
address:
"testaddress"
email:
"testemail"
name:
"test"
-MCr3jCuPQ4MwOEYCDwS
address:
"testaddress2"
email:
"testemail2"
name:
"test2"
-MCtJKw6iqflovcl1NEJ
address:
"testaddress3"
email:
"testemail3"
name:
"test3"

```
function getData(data) {
var database=firebase.database();
var rootRef=database.ref("information");
rootRef.on("value",gotData,errData);
}

function gotData(data){
//console.log(data.val());
var information = data.val();
var keys = Object.keys(information);
//console.log(keys);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var k = keys[i];
    var name = information[k].name;
    var email = information[k].email;
    var address = information[k].address;
    console.log(name,email,address);                
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(name);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    var buttonNode = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    buttonNode.innerHTML="Click for Details";
    buttonNode.addEventListener('click',() =>{
    alert("the email is: " + email + " and address is: " + address);
    });
    var retrievedName = document.getElementById("wow").appendChild(node).appendChild(buttonNode);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred solution is using data attributes to store the information on the button itself.

so add the following lines AFTER the `var buttonNode` line.

```
buttonNode.setAttribute("data-email",email);
buttonNode.setAttribute("data-address",address);
```

Then replacing your click handler with:

```
buttonNode.addEventListener('click',(e) =>{
     var btn = e.target;
     alert("the email is: " + btn.getAttribute("data-email") + " and address is: " + btn.getAttribute("data-address"));
});
```